Using the same image across different scenes
I’m a newbie with Godot (or any game engine, actually) and I’m working in a small personal project where I need the same background image to be used across multiple scenes. Is there a way to do it without including a TextureRect in every scene?
So far, I couldn't find any answer for that yet. So any help is appreciated

I don't know if there are any alternatives to your problem.
But if it was my project, I would save the TextureRect's branch as a scene. Then all you will have to do, is use that scene everytime you need it, instead of having to create a new TextureRect. Here's how you save a branch as a scene
If that is not what you had in mind. Then hit me up
